# function overloading and parameter inheritance

Tags: c++, overload-resolution

In the following code

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A {

};

class B : public A {

};

class C {
public:
  void foo(const A& a) { cout << "A";}
  void foo(const B& b) { cout << "B";}
};
int main() {
    C c;
    const A& o = B();
    c.foo(o);
  
}
```

I'd like the result to be "B", instead it is "A".
Is there any way that I could call `void foo(const B& b)` without resorting to  `dynamic_cast`  ?

**EDIT**: What I want to achieve is for the different functions to obtain different resources from C (i.e some member variables). I could do use virtual functions on A and B and do something like this

```
void foo(const A& o) {
  o.bar(this)
}
```

and then A or B would gather the resources from C, but I do not want for A or B to know about C.

Comment: Overloading does nothing hear. Look towards virtual functions.

Comment: Okay, firstly, the behavior is undefined because `const A& o = B();` stores a reference to a destroyed object.  Secondly, the _type_ of `o` is only known to be an instance of `A` or some subclass.  It _cannot_ know that `o` actually refers to a `B` instance.

Comment: @paddy - Nothing undefined. This falls under the cases of reference lifetime extension.

Comment: @paddy why it cannot know? The compiler knows that o is a subclass of B.

Comment: And I'm guessing reference lifetime extension is what makes the OP want that `c.foo(o);` would print `B`? The fact the compiler must do the right thing (TM) to extend the temporary `B`'s lifetime?

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica I'm not sure if I understand your question, but i was using lifetime extension on purpose.

Comment: @S.M. The fact is that I want the two functions to obtain different resources from C depending on the parameter types. I don't see how virtual functions could help on that situation.

Comment: @perencia It doesn't matter that `B` is a subclass of `A`.  The problem is that `o` is of type `const A&` which is not automatically deducible as type `const B&`.  Deriving a `const B&` from `o` would require a static cast (if you know for sure it's a `B` instance) or a dynamic cast.

Comment: You need polymorphism

Comment: This could be done with double dispatching and the visitor pattern: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern

Answer (score 2):

In a comment you said

> why it cannot know? The compiler knows that o is a subclass of B.

The phrasing here contains an inherent misunderstanding. `o` is not a subclass of `B`, but rather a reference.

As far as references are concerned, the C++ type system doesn't bother itself much with the circumstances of a reference's initialization. It operates under the simple assumption that a reference is bound to a valid object of a known type. And in your case, it is. It's bound to an `A` sub-object of a lifetime extended `B`.

After that, the id-expression `o` is always going to be an lvalue of type `A const`. That's how the type system works, and that's why overload resolution is always going to prefer the overload that print's `A`. All expressions have a static type.

To achieve a similar effects to what you are after, we employ design patterns around dynamic dispatch. Notable of those are the visitor pattern and the non-virtual interface pattern (AKA "template method" outside the C++osphere).

Answer (score 1):

Your goal is this:

```
What I want to achieve is for the different functions to obtain different resources from C (i.e some member variables).
```

This is a typical application of the visitor pattern without using `dynamic_casts`. Keep in mind that this only works with pointers:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A;
class B;

class C 
{
public:
    void foo(const A& a) { cout << "A";}
    void foo(const B& b) { cout << "B";}
};

struct Visitor
{
    Visitor(C& c) : _C{c} {}   

    void Visit(A* a)
    {
        _C.foo(*a);
    }

    void Visit(B* b)
    {
        _C.foo(*b);
    }

private:
    C& _C;
};

class A 
{
public:
    virtual void Accept(Visitor& visitor)
    {
        visitor.Visit(this);
    }
};

class B : public A 
{
public:
    void Accept(Visitor& visitor) override
    {
        visitor.Visit(this);
    }
};

int main() 
{
    C c;
    A* a = new B();
    Visitor v(c);
    a->Accept(v);
}
```

Comment: You should make your visitor an interface, so `A`/`B` really doesn't know `C` (even though `Visitor`).

Answer (score 1):

Easy way is indeed virtual methods in `A`:

```
struct A {
  virtual ~A() = default;
  virtual void foo(const C& c) { std::cout << "A" << c.n;}
};

struct B : public A {
  void foo(const C& c) override { std::cout << "B" << c.n;}
};

struct C {
  int n = 42;
  void foo(const A& a) { a.foo(*this); }
};

int main() {
    C c;
    const A& o = B();
    c.foo(o);
}
```

But indeed, then, `A`/`B` know `C`.

You might reverse dependency with visitor pattern (but then visitor should know the whole hierarchy):

```
struct A;
struct B;

struct IVisitor
{
    virtual ~IVisitor() = default;
    virtual void visit(A&) = 0;
    virtual void visit(B&) = 0;
};

struct A {
  virtual ~A() = default;
  virtual void accept(IVisitor& v) { v.visit(*this); }
};

struct B : public A {
  void accept(IVisitor& v) override { v.visit(*this); }
};

class C {
public:
  void foo(const A& a) { cout << "A";}
  void foo(const B& b) { cout << "B";}
};

struct Visitor : IVisitor
{
    C& c;
    void visit(A&) override { c.foo(a); }
    void visit(B&) override { c.foo(b); }
};

int main() {
    C c;
    const A& o = B();
    o.accept(Visitor{c});
}
```

Since C++17, `std::variant` might help for the dispatch, as it provide `std::visit`:

```
struct A {};
struct B {}; // inheritance no longer required.
             // If you keep inheritance,
             // virtual std::varaint<A*, B*> to_variant() { return this; }
             // might be useful

using A_or_B = std::variant<A, B>;

class C {
public:
  void foo(const A& a) { cout << "A";}
  void foo(const B& b) { cout << "B";}
};

int main()
{
    C c;
    const A_or_B o = B();
    std::visit([&c](auto& a_or_b) { c.foo(a_or_b); }, o);
}
```

Comment: Very interesting.